# OpenGL texture randomly not shown

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I have got a *very, very strange* problem in my **C++ OpenGL** application.

I simply load a texture and apply it to a quadric:

```
glGenTextures(1, &tex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

Then

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
gluQuadricDrawStyle(quad,GLU_FILL);
gluQuadricTexture(quad,GL_TRUE);
gluCylinder(quad,1,0,2,20,1);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Now: it works perfectly 9 times out of ten, but sometimes the texture isn't shown (the quadric stays white).

The `image` is correctly loaded, so the problem should be with OpenGL. I have tried with several different images too. Always `GL_NO_ERROR`.

Any idea ? It is driving me crazy...

Comment: Kinda silly but on the times where it doesn't load, if you minimize then maximize the window, does it appear?

Comment: No, it doesn't load, even if I minimize/maximize.

Comment: Can you test it on a different PC or with different drivers?

Comment: By "texture isn't shown" do you mean when you restart the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found :) It was the `GLint texture` member that wasn't correctly reallocated in the copy constructor.

However, i still don't understand why it worked sometimes...

Answer (score 1):

The code you are using seems valid. Have you ...

- tried to use a simple quad instead of the quadric
- assured that `image` is filled correctly
- verified that `tex` is not altered somewhere else
- assured that no other programs are using opengl at the same time
- restarted your computer ;)